# Change this grid from 2 columns to 3 columns

Tags: php, gridview

I am a very basic dabbler with code and css and found this code (below ) which changes the blog post layout on my in-progress site from a list to 2 post columns and in as many rows as required.

However I wondered if there was a relatively simple method of changing this to 3 columns from 2 which would be easy enough for me to understand?

Many thanks in advance.

Gavin

Code:

```
<?php $counter=1;global       $query_string;query_posts($query_string.'&caller_get_posts=1&posts_per_page=4');if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();if($counter==1):?>

<div class="row cols2">
<div class="col"><?php elseif($counter==2): ?><div class="col"><?php endif; ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('default-thumb')?></a>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt() ?>
</div><!-- /.col -->

<?php if($counter==2): ?></div><!-- /.row cols2 -->
<?php $counter=0;endif;$counter++;endwhile;if($counter==2):?></div><!-- /.row cols2 --><?php         endif;endif; ?>
```